# Search and replace parts of files by line numbers

Tags: ruby, regex, file, copy

I'd like to write a Ruby script that would copy specific lines of code from one file and insert them into another file. I'd like, if possible, the result to be the same as if I had highlighted some lines in file_1, copied them, then placed my cursor in the middle of file_2 and pasted the copied code in (ie. code in file_2 that's beneath the insertion point would move down...).

I have written scripts in the past that take the entire contents of a file and insert it into an empty file, but I'd like just certain lines from one file to be "copied and pasted" into the middle of another file. Is it possible to search a file by line number? Is my overall goal possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean for this to be a desktop application?

Comment: It is not clear what kind of interface you are expecting. Is it a method, or is it a standalone app, etc.? From what you describe, this looks to me that it should be a script to be added onto a text editor. So it should be written in, for example in e-lisp if you are using emacs rather than in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try each_with_index, if you can keep the whole file in memory the script is pretty straightforward.

```
IO.readlines("/etc/passwd").each_with_index do |line, line_num|
  if (line_num % 6 == 2)
    puts line 
  end
end
```

You can then redirect to a new file or open up a new one and write to that using

```
opened_file.puts line
```

If you have the list of line numbers you could just walk through those too:

```
lines = IO.readlines(file)
line_numbers.each do |i|
   puts lines[i]
end
```

Comment: Well, even though some people didn't understand my question, you seem to have Paul... this is exactly what I was looking for...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the split function to turn your text into an array and the you can select the lines by number or even a range:

```
arraytext = filetext.Split("\n")
arraytext[0] #for first line
```